# Proof of Existence of $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis

**Thm**: For every real $x>0$ and every integer $n>0$ there is one and only one positive real $y$ such that $y^n=x$.

It's a theorem from Rudin's PMA. Here is the outline of my proof:

The uniqueness is obvious. To prove the existence, let $E=\{t | t>0,t^n<x\}$. By least upper bound property, there exists a real $y$ such that $y=\sup E$.  We claim that this $y$ is desired. If $y^n<x$, then we could find a $h>0$ that $(y+h)^n<x$, this contradicts the fact that $y$ is an upper bound. (I glossed over the details cause I don't have any questions about this part. )

If $y^n>x$, we will show that $y$ is not the least upper bound. To make it explicit, we need to find a positive $k$ made $y-k$ an upper bound of $E$, i.e. $[t\in E\Rightarrow t\leq y-k]$. $t\in E$ means $t^n<x$. So our goal now is to prove $[t^n<x\Rightarrow t\leq y-k]$. Rewrite the statement as its contrapositive $[t>y-k\Rightarrow t^n\geq x]$. Choose $k$ so that $0<k<\frac{y^n-x}{ny^{n-1}}$. If $t>y-k$, then $y^n-t^n<y^n-(y-k)^n<kny^{n-1}<y^n-x$. Hence $t^n>x$. So $t^n\geq x$ also holds. So $[t>y-k\Rightarrow t^n\geq x]$ has been proved. Therefore $y-k$ is also an upper bound of $E$. But $y-k<y$, this contradicts the fact that $y$ is the least.

Hence $y^n=x$.

---

But Rudin's proof is slightly different from mine. His proof is quoted below:

... ...

Assume $y^n>x$. Put
$$k=\frac{y^n-x}{ny^{n-1}}$$
Then $0<k<y$. If $t\geq y-k$, we conclude that
$$y^n-t^n\leq y^n-(y-k)^n<kny^{n-1}=y^n-x$$
Thus $t^n>x$, and $t\notin E$. It follows that $y-k$ is an upper bound of $E$.

... ...

He actually proved $[t\geq y-k \Rightarrow t^n>x]$ and I don't see why. After all, by the definition of upper bounds, if $y-k$ is an upper bound, then $t\leq y-k$ for all $t$ is enough. (So the negation is $t>y-k$). Why does Rudin use $\geq$ here instead of $>$? And is my proof wrong?

Comment: You should prove explicitly that $E$ has an upper bound. (I realize this is an outline, so you might have proved it in the full proof)

Comment: You’ve shown that $y-k\notin E,$ and also proved that if $u\notin E,$ $u>0,$ then when $t>u,$ $t\notin E,$ and deducing $y-k$ is an upper bound. Rudin is putting those two arguments into one.